# Identify the forecolor and backcolor using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

[image: Sample screenshot]

I am pretty new to Python and OpenCV. I have some screenshots (attached one sample for reference) for which I want to identify the forecolor and backcolor of the Text. I will be using this colors for calculating the color contrast ratio for the text. Using pytesseract, I am able to identify the words and drawn bounding rectangles to the text. Can anyone guide me how can I detect the forecolor and backcolor of the text? Below is the code which I did so far.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

imgOriginal = cv2.imread('3.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(imgOriginal, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (3,3), 0)
cv2.imshow("Filtered",img)

### Detecting words
hImg,wImg,_ = imgOriginal.shape
boxes = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, config='--psm 6') #list
for i,b in enumerate(boxes.splitlines()):
    if i!=0: #no need to extract the first row since it is the header
        b=b.split()
        if len(b)==12: #12th item is the word
            x, y, w, h = int(b[6]), int(b[7]), int(b[8]), int(b[9])
            cv2.rectangle(imgOriginal, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 1)
            
            
cv2.imshow('Image',imgOriginal)

k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k==ord('q'):
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: could you please attach an example image to your question

Comment: @SAITARUNUPPARI, I have attached a screenshot image. Its basically the screens of some windows applications

Comment: you mean back color and forecolor refer to the color of the text(black) and the background greyish(ash) color. is that it?

Comment: @SAITARUNUPPARI,Yes, we have hundreds of screens and in some screens there are different back/fore colors.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are still looking for an answer.

```
imgOriginal = cv2.imread('windows.png')
image = imgOriginal.copy()
image_1 = imgOriginal.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(imgOriginal, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Removing the horizantal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7,1))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 2)

# Removing the vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,7))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 2)

gray_no_lines = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
otsu = cv2.threshold(gray_no_lines, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

### Detecting words
boxes = pytesseract.image_to_data(otsu, config='--psm 6') #list

xs = []
ys = []
ws = []
hs = []
words = []
for i,b in enumerate(boxes.splitlines()):
    if i!=0: #no need to extract the first row since it is the header
        b=b.split()
        if len(b)==12: #12th item is the word
            if b[11] != -1:
                x, y, w, h = int(b[6]), int(b[7]), int(b[8]), int(b[9])
                cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 1)
                xs.append(x)
                ys.append(y)
                ws.append(w)
                hs.append(h)
                words.append(b[11])
text_colors = []
bg_colors = []
for j in range(len(words)):
    x,y,w,h = xs[j],ys[j],ws[j],hs[j]
    roi_otsu = otsu[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    roi_image = image_1[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        
    black_coords = np.column_stack(np.where(roi_otsu == 0))
    white_coords = np.column_stack(np.where(roi_otsu == 255))
    
    blues_text = []
    greens_text = []
    reds_text = []
    blues_bg = []
    greens_bg = []
    reds_bg = []

    for i in range(len(black_coords)):
        blue_t = roi_image.item(black_coords[i][0],black_coords[i][1],0)
        green_t = roi_image.item(black_coords[i][0],black_coords[i][1],1)
        red_t = roi_image.item(black_coords[i][0],black_coords[i][1],2)
        blues_text.append(blue_t)
        greens_text.append(green_t)
        reds_text.append(red_t)
        
    color_t = (int(np.mean(blues_text)),int(np.mean(greens_text)),int(np.mean(reds_text)))
    for i in range(len(white_coords)):
        blue_bg = roi_image.item(white_coords[i][0],white_coords[i][1],0)
        green_bg = roi_image.item(white_coords[i][0],white_coords[i][1],1)
        red_bg = roi_image.item(white_coords[i][0],white_coords[i][1],2)
        blues_bg.append(blue_bg)
        greens_bg.append(green_bg)
        reds_bg.append(red_bg)
        
    color_bg = (int(np.mean(blues_bg)),int(np.mean(greens_bg)),int(np.mean(reds_bg)))

    text_colors.append(color_t)
    bg_colors.append(color_bg)

print(text_colors)
print(bg_colors)

# print(len(text_colors),len(bg_colors))
```

I have removed the horizontal and vertical lines for better results. binarised the image and collected the coordinates of each text region. sliced the region of interests and collected the pixel coordinated of text and background(from the binarised sliced region). collected the pixel values of those coordinates from the color-sliced region. Took the average of each color and appended the color to a final list.

Hope this solves your problem. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks Tarun for the answer. I will try this and let you know the result.